# how to edit a legend with overlaying shapes color and text with ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, legend

I have a plot with the following code:

```
p <- ggplot(df.melt, aes(BP, neglogpval, color=test, shape=test)) +
  geom_jitter() + 
  geom_point(data=df.melt.onegene, colour="black") +
  geom_text(data=df.melt.onegene, label="gene", vjust=1)
```

The plot overall is showing what i want it to show, however, there are two things with the legend i would love to fix:

**1. I would like to change the name of the legend from 'test' to 'Legend'.

2. You can see that the legend has overlays on the icon (there's a color, a letter, and a symbol all on top of each other).  I just want the color to be present there.  How do I fix this?!**

The structure of my data table is something like this:

```
gene     neglogpval      BP         test
 G1        .5          490000000    test1
 G1        .1          490000000    test2
 G1        .9          490000000    test3
 G1        1.7         490000000    test4
 G2        .6          488001000    test1
 G2        .2          488001000    test2
 G2        .82         488001000    test3
 G2        1.4         488001000    test4
```

[image]

Comment: Add `show.legend=FALSE` inside `geom_text` and `geom_point`. Add `+ labs(colour="Legend")` to change the legend title, or, better yet `+ labs(colour="")`.

Comment: The first question can be answered by searching the internet for "change legend title ggplot2". Second question is a duplicate.